# Force back button to apear in full screen mode on Android tablets

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I am making a game which will work on android phones and tablets.
I am using full-screen mode to render.

In my game, you can press the back button to go back.

On my phone, the back button is allways available.
On a tablet, it disapears during full screen mode.

Can I force the on-screen buttons to remain without compiling to a lower SDK version?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

From official [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html)

> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN
>   flag. When set, this flag enables “low profile" mode for the system
>   bar or navigation bar. Navigation buttons dim and other elements in
>   the system bar also hide. Enabling this is useful for creating more
>   immersive games without distraction for the system navigation buttons.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE flag
>   to request the system bar or navigation bar be visible.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is a new flag that requests the
>   navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the
>   navigation bar used by some handsets (it does not hide the system
>   bar on tablets). The navigation bar returns to view as soon as the
>   system receives user input. As such, this mode is useful primarily for
>   video playback or other cases in which the whole screen is needed but
>   user input is not required.